# How to find a domain at which a function is non-zero

Tags: functions

Consider some function f[x,y]. Is there any way to find a domain at which it is non-zero?

Namely, I would like to compute the integral

```
Integrate[f[x,y],{x,y} \[In] R]
```

where R is a region at which f[x,y] is non-zero. How to compute R?

Comment: `Reduce[{f[x,y]!=0, (x|y)\[Element] Reals]` might work. Any specific examples?

Comment: As for your edited question, use `Integrate[f[x,y], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}]` and let Mathematica do the work for you. Again, any specific examples?

Comment: What is the difference between `Integrate[f[x,y],{x,y} \[In] R] ` 

and 

`Integrate[f[x,y],{x,y}] `
? 

From the computational point of view, mathematically zero

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : Mathematica integrates my integral using Monte Carlo method. It is very sensitive to the domain of the definition. If I simply use infinite integration limits that it will give zero.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform : when trying to use Reduce it answers
"Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or \
the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers \
present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce \
require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the \
system may help.".

Comment: @JohnTaylor That is precisely why I asked you to include an example of what `f[x,y]` looks like. Numeric integration and symbolic integration are two different beasts.